# Swiffy replacing v5.2 to v5.1 making the files not working

Tags: google-swiffy

I have this swf of map locations. However, I didn't put the map background inside the swf since it will be too big and I won't be able to convert it. Now the problem is the swiffy background can't be transparent even if I remove the backgroundColor. Replacing the v5.2 to 5.1 making the whole locations icon disappear and the whole thing become black.

I have the same map with different function that I converted in 5.1 and it's still working well. Is there any way to convert my new map using v5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, relying on a online "compiler" makes large product development and maintenance darn near impossible or at least terribly frustrating.  I've asked Google numerous times for a stand alone compiler, and they aren't interested in sharing it right now.  We've just got to move along with them and rebuild every file with each update for reasons similar to yours.

Here is a possible work-around for you:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #div > *:first-child {
          background-color: transparent !important;
    }
</style>
```